# Problemas al realizar programa que resuelve la regla de ruffini

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy tratando de realizar un programa en Python que resuelva el ejercicio matemático de la regla de ruffini, aclaro esto ya que puede servir para interpretar mejor lo que se quiere hacer con el código. Al momento de ejecutarlo me surgen varios errores, y nunca llego al punto de que funcione como debería. Para el que no sepa, lo que se intenta hacer es que el primer número a dividir (en el código, números_dividir[0]) se multiplique por el divisor(divisor), ese resultado (resultados_m) debe sumarse con el siguiente número a dividir, para luego a ese número (resultados_f) multiplicarlo con el divisor nuevamente. Este procedimiento se sigue hasta que no haya más números. Adjunto el código y el problema que me ocasiona actualmente. Desde ya, gracias.

````
divisor = int (input('Ingrese el divisor: '))
numeros_dividir = []
resultados_m = []
resultados_f = []

def agregar_numeros () : #Agregar numeros a dividir
    while True : #Repite ciclo hasta que se rompa
        numero_str = input('Ingrese los valores de a uno sin la variable y ordenados. En caso de ya haberlo hecho, escribir Listo: ')
        if numero_str.isdigit() : #Comprueba que sea un nro
            numero_int = int(numero_str) #convierte str en int
            numeros_dividir.append(numero_int) #agrega los nros al array
            print(f'Numeros agregados hasta el momento: {numeros_dividir}')
        elif numero_str == 'Listo': #termina el ciclo
            resultados_m.append(numeros_dividir[0] * divisor) #agrega resultado de la multiplicación a una variable
            resultados_f.append(numeros_dividir[0]) #agrega primer numero como resultado final
            return False
        elif not numero_str.isdigit(): #en caso de que no sea un numero
            print ('el valor ingresado no es valido')


def operacion():
    for i, j in range(1, len(resultados_f)), range(len(resultados_m)): #iteracion para hacer sum y multip, arranca en 1 ya que el 0 ya fue resuelto
        resultados_m.append(resultados_f[i] * divisor) #MULTIPLICACION
        resultados_f.append(numeros_dividir[i] + resultados_m[j]) #SUMA

agregar_numeros()
operacion() 

#ERROR
for i, j in range(len(resultados_f)), range(len(resultados_m)):
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) ```
````

Comment: prueba poner `for i, j in zip(range(len(resultados_f)), range(len(resultados_m))):` donde está tu error

Comment: Agregandole el zip pude hacer que no me tire ningún error, pero el código no entra nunca al ciclo for. Gracias igualmente!

Comment: estoy notando que en `operacion`no hay ningún tipo de impresión en la consola, ¿no será que tienes que imprimir el resultado en la consola y como no estás viendo nada te de la sensación de que no está entrando en el `for`? intenta poner algún tipo de mensaje antes de entrar al bucle y dentro del mismo para verificar si realemte está ejecutando correctamente.

Comment: No está entrando en el ciclo for ya que yo le estoy indicando que arranque desde el indice 1 de resultados_f, porque si arranca desde 0 no me sirve ya que daría otro resultado. Igualmente, si le quito el 1 y dejo que funcione desde 0, itera una sola vez en el ciclo, lo comprobé imprimiendo i y j. Tengo que tratar de obtener resultados_f[1] antes de entrar al ciclo para ver si así funciona, seguiré intentando. Gracias!